# Per-application volume control in windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, audio

Is there a way either built-in (don't think there is) or via a third-party to specify the volume on a per application basis in Windows XP? For example, right now I am listening to some music on fairly loudly and I would like all of the alerts I am getting from other apps (email, twitter updates, IMs) to be reduced.